# listening for touchend sometimes fires click event mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, cordova

I have an app im building with phonegap.

I'm listening for touchstart/ touchend events to make it responsive.

Sometimes, the event listener for the touchend will fire, but then, for e.g, an input will focus afterwards as the click event is fired 300ms later.

an example is, i have a menu sidebar. each sidebar list item listens to the touchend event. on receiving the event, the sidebar closes and the relevant page is shown. however, if the relevant page contains a form element that is where the user had clicked for the sidebar list item, the form element will get focused.

what is the best way to stop this across the entire app? it happens in various scenarios which vary with different phones.

Ive tried things like stopPropagation etc but these only work ina  few cases, and i need to have a generic cross-app solution rather than adding in for each function, if possible.

something like:

```
$('body').on('touchend', function(){
    //stop any further touchends/ clicks from firing
    //apart from the 1 i do want
})
```

Comment: Have you tried `event.preventDefault()`?

Comment: You should take a look at [hammer.js](http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/) - it does all the heavy lifting for this sort of thing

Comment: hi, again this works sometimes but doesn't seem to work for every situation edit: for the preventDefault() option

Answer (score 0):

You could try 'touchcancel' instead of 'touchend', see if it works :) good luck.

Answer (score 0):

your app goes to fast ;)
EASY WAY:
just put a setTimeout(gotopage(),100) 
on every button/menu action

HARD WAY:
If you really don't want to put a setTimeout, you should take a look to how bubbling works, problem is here

TIP:
Anyway to avoid the 300ms you should use the Fastclick of FTLABS :
https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick
and the use click event, it will do the job for you (you will still have to use setimeout trick)